# Neo4j: How could I add a date created (or modified) on every node's properties?

Tags: neo4j, properties, timestamp, cypher, nodes

I created a web application that use a Neo4j database and I need to know when a property is created or modified by an user.
Do you have any advices for me?
I thought to modify every property in an array where there will be the real value of property and a timestamp value (but I don't know how to do).

Comment: Let me rephrase to see if I understand what you want :
You have nodes with multiple properties and you want to know, for each of those properties, when they were updated (basically a date for each property). Is that right ?

Comment: @Muldec yes I would like to have a data for each property.

Comment: I don't see the point of that, but why wouldn't you create a date property for all your poperties (basically duplicates them) ? That way your data is consistent and you have a date for each fields.

Comment: Where does that hard requirement come from? And what would you use them for? If it's just for auditing would probably better to write an audit log.

Comment: Basically I have a web application based on Neo4j and on this application the users can do the data edit, so I need to know when the data are modified to save them on Hive table (behind Neo4j db).